# VS Code PowerShell terminal doesn't execute Connect-ExchangeOnline command

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, exchange-server

I use Visual Studio Code 1.72.1 on Windows 11 (Parallels ARM Virtual Machine). VS Code has the "main" PS plugin installed:

```
Name: PowerShell
Id: ms-vscode.powershell
Description: Develop PowerShell modules, commands and scripts in Visual Studio Code!
Version: 2022.8.5
Publisher: Microsoft
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell
```

I have a simple script ConnectExchangeOnline.ps1 with only two lines in it

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

`ExchangeOnlineManagement` is already installed.
Running this script in VS Code doesn't produce any results (it just "hangs")
[image]

Additionally, executing `Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com` hangs as well
[image]

Executing the same command in PowerShell or PS IDE works flawlessly
[image]

So it's clear that the problem with VS Code and its inability to run PS commands.

Comment: Seems like the VScode environment is isolated and can't pass on the MultiFactor request. Nothing to do with not running the commands.

Answer (score 0):

ExchangeOnlineManagement v3?
I had to recently to get connected

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).